# Is 'thrive to become' used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I came upon a sentence *'Thrive to become an efficient and adaptive IT organisation'* describing future company goals.

It seems to me that *'strive'* would be more appropriate word here.
Is *'thrive'* used correctly in this sentence/context and can *thrive/strive* be used interchangeably?

Comment: Do dictionaries indicate or suggest that 'thrive' and 'strive' are interchangeable, at least in the example you give?

Comment: I didn't find any examples like this where someone would **thrive to become** something in the future

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Prosper', unlike 'strive', is a close synonym of 'thrive'. (Illustrations using 'prosper' are perhaps more accessible.)

> *prosper* verb (used without object)
>
> to be successful or fortunate, especially in financial respects;
>   *thrive*; flourish. [[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prospers)]

Sentences such as

> - The home of the famous Yorkshire Mixture, Joseph Dobson’s is a
>     fascinating story of a family owned business, which has prospered to
>     become one of the largest family owned confectionery manufacturers in
>     England. [[Dobsons UK – our business](https://www.dobsons.co.uk/our-story)]

where 'to become ...' is an **adjunct** containing additional closely connected (showing results / expanding on the matrix sentence) material, are quite acceptable.

- '*which has prospered to become* ...' could be replaced by
- '*which has prospered greatly, becoming* ...' or
- '*which has prospered greatly – so much so, that it has become* ...'. ('greatly' added merely to lubricate)

> - From then on Bloomsbury has thrived to become arguably the best known
>     cultural group in the Western world ... [[The Handbook to the
>     Bloomsbury
>     Group](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ICJZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22thrived+to+become%22&source=bl&ots=uhsJNhrMAC&sig=ACfU3U194CFhoJrUazbiCu_w1yBJtVIOrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU1bT0gpXnAhXNi1wKHVGcBIQQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22thrived%20to%20become%22&f=false)]

is an example of the same king using 'thrive'.

So the sentence 'They prospered/thrived to become one of the largest ...' is by no means unacceptable (though I'd use the -ing form 'becoming' instead here).

However, the injunction 'Thrive' or 'Prosper' sounds very strange here, belonging in a  religious or otherwise supernatural domain. One can't say that 'Thrive! Become an efficient and adaptive IT organisation!' is ungrammatical, but it's certainly verging on the outlandish.

It's quite likely, as I think you suspect, that 'Strive [= 'try your utmost'] to become an efficient and adaptive IT organisation', where *strive* (like try, attempt, seek) takes a to-infinitive clause thus forming a **catenation**, is what was intended, and that this is a malapropism.

Comment: The wrong usage seems much clearer when thrive is replaced with synonym prosper, thanks